# Avoid click in two elements with angular

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML:

```
  <div data-ng-repeat='image in model.images' data-ng-click="open(image)" class="image">
    <img src="{{image.Url}}" alt="" />
    <a href="" data-ng-click="vote(image)" class="vote"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a>
    <span>{{image.Votes}}</span>
  </div>
```

And the following Javascript:

```
 application.controller('ImageController', function ImageController($scope, ImageService, ngDialog) {

    $scope.model = {
      images: [],
      loading: false,
      pages: { instagram: '' }          
    }

    var load = function () {
      $scope.model.loading = true;
      ImageService.GetList($scope.model.pages.instagram)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.model.images = $scope.model.images.concat(data.Images)
          $scope.model.pages.instagram = data.NextInstagramPage;
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { })
        .finally(function () {
          $scope.model.loading = false
        });;
    }

    $scope.loader = function () {
      return $scope.model.loading ? 'loading' : 'load more';
    }

    $scope.open = function (image) {
      var scope = $scope.$new();
      scope.model = { image: image };
      ngDialog.open({
        className: "dialog",
        plain: false,
        scope: scope,            
        template: 'image'
      });
    };

    $scope.vote = function (image) {
      ImageService.Vote(image)
         .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { })
         .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { });
    };

    load();

  });
```

The problem is when I click on vote both actions take place: open and vote.

This is because vote is inside the div image?

How should I avoid this?

**UPDATE**

I also tried the following which seems to work:

```
  application.directive('stopPropagation', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        element.bind(attr.stopPropagation, function (e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Then use it as follows:

```
<a href="" data-ng-click="vote(image)" data-stop-propagation="click" class="vote"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a>
```

Does anyone sees any problem in using such a directive for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you code to following. You need to stop event propagation

```
 <div data-ng-repeat='image in model.images' data-ng-click="open(image, $event)" class="image">
        <img src="{{image.Url}}" alt="" />
        <a href="" data-ng-click="vote(image, $event)" class="vote"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a>
        <span>{{image.Votes}}</span>
      </div>





 application.controller('ImageController', function ImageController($scope, ImageService, ngDialog) {

        $scope.model = {
          images: [],
          loading: false,
          pages: { instagram: '' }          
        }

        var load = function () {
          $scope.model.loading = true;
          ImageService.GetList($scope.model.pages.instagram)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.model.images = $scope.model.images.concat(data.Images)
              $scope.model.pages.instagram = data.NextInstagramPage;
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { })
            .finally(function () {
              $scope.model.loading = false
            });;
        }

        $scope.loader = function () {
          return $scope.model.loading ? 'loading' : 'load more';
        }

        $scope.open = function (image, $event) {
          var scope = $scope.$new();
          scope.model = { image: image };
          ngDialog.open({
            className: "dialog",
            plain: false,
            scope: scope,            
            template: 'image'
          });

          $event.stopPropagation();
        };

        $scope.vote = function (image, $event) {
 $event.stopPropagation();          
ImageService.Vote(image)
             .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { })
             .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { });
        };

        load();

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the event is bubbling. Both elements are capturing it. You could use `event.stopPropagation` to stop the event from propagation or `event.preventDefault` to prevent the default behavior of the event and implement by yourself.